# Bloquear rotas de acordo com a permissão do usuário AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, route, permissões

Tenho um sistema aonde faço o login de um usuário, caso de tudo certo o servidor me retorna um objeto e eu armazeno esse objeto na `sessionStorage`. Consigo recuperar esse objeto para fazer algumas validações, ex: renderizar alguns componentes de acordo com a permissão do usuário.

Gostaria de bloquear algumas rotas de acordo com a permissão do usuário, ou seja, se o usuário tiver `permissão = 2` ele não poderá acessar essa rota: `/usuario`

A configuração da rota é a seguinte:

```
angular.module("oraculo").config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/usuario", {
        templateUrl: "public/views/usuario.html",
        controller: "usuarioCtrl"
    });


    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/login"});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitore a fila de notificações pelo evento `$locationChangeStart`, e se necessário cancele o evento:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if (!validaPermissoesUsuario()) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Ou, alternativamente, redirecione o usuário:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if (!validaPermissoesUsuario()) {
       $location.path( "/naoAutorizado" );
    }
});
```

Uma outra opção é implementar, na configuração de rotas, um termo `otherwise` que interprete e manipule a rota requerida:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: function() {
        //Descreva sua validação de permissões aqui.
        return '/naoAutorizado';
    }
});
```

Entretanto, a maneira como eu recomendaria seria por avaliação do lado do serviço. Caso o usuário logado não tenha permissões, retorne `401 Unauthorized` e configure sua view de acordo.

Comment: Entendi, isso eu faria nesse `config` de rotas ou no `controller` de cada pagina?

Comment: Como `broadcast`s podem ser anunciados para toda a aplicação, este código poderia estar dentro de um serviço - responsável apenas pela monitoração de mudanças de rota e redirecionamento caso necessário.

Comment: @Techies eu incluí um exemplo para ser inserido na configuração de rota também.

Comment: Beleza kk, estou pensando, teria como utilizar o `resolve` para fazer essa validação?

Comment: @Techies sim, é possível. Entretanto eu incluí uma outra sugestão que pode ser mais útil a você, verifique a resposta editada.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar dessa forma.

Comment: @OnoSendai O problema de validar no serviço (servidor?) é que a função otherwise espera ou uma string com a rota ou uma função que será executada de forma síncrona, as requests como são assíncronas não seriam esperadas, logo, o bloco seguinte continuaria a execução. Uma solução que encontrei são os estados futuros, que implementam rotas assíncronas, permitindo maior flexibilidade, veja nesse [link](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future)

Comment: @OnoSendai Nesse caso, deixo o comentário para o AP se ele desejar algo mais flexível, particularmente eu preferiria future states se minha aplicação apenas consumisse uma API, pois a cada troca de estados eu poderia verificar se o token de autenticação ainda está válido. Apesar de que, não sei se reduziria a escalabilidade da aplicação ao fazer isso, mas acredito que não...sei... rs

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound A solução que você apresentou é valida - o que eu quis dizer com a última parte é que você pode, por exemplo, carregar o set de permissões do usuário do lado do JS, e via validação síncrona controlar o fluxo. Via servidor, um método comum é implementar um Injector que, ao receber estados HTTP específicos (por exemplo `403 Forbidden`), force a rota para uma página que faça o *handling* correto.

Comment: @OnoSendai Entendido! Realmente, trabalho com aplicações que controlam via server como você citou, estamos trabalhando numa solução para controlar no Browser, estamos em um dilema se iremos fazer da forma que você disse, sincronamente ou iremos utilizar o future states. Postei o comentário para que se alguém já tivesse utilizado esse extra do ui-router e soubesse de alguma problema/ou vantagem também pudesse comentar, além de, é claro, sugerir ao AP e mostrá-lo outro caminho.